# Getting 403 for images via img_auth.php after upgrading MediaWiki from 1.21 to 1.27

Tags: image, mediawiki

I have a MediaWiki installation that I recently upgraded from 1.21 to 1.27 and where I use [img_auth.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Img_auth.php).

One of the issues that happened is the fact that images stopped displaying. I am getting a 403 forbidden code when opening.

These images exist, I checked and I was able to discover that this is due to the fact that these images are not present in the database images table. When I insert them manually, they display.

This leads me to 2 hypotheses:

1. MediaWiki policy regarding images changed and it's now stricter requiring all images to be in the images table.
2. Some configuration actually changed and I need to update it to get images displaying again. (I didn't do the initial config for this installation.)
3. Something else?

What can be the cause of such behaviour?

Comment: A DB record should not be needed for thumbnails. Check the HTTP response message and the `img_auth` log channel. (How do you even get thumbnails with no matching DB records, though?)

Answer (score 1):

There were multiple changes between [img_auth.php in 1.21](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/diffusion/MW/browse/REL1_21/img_auth.php) and [in 1.27](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/diffusion/MW/browse/REL1_27/img_auth.php).

If adding files to the [image table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Image_table) makes them work again, maybe the [fileExists() check](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/diffusion/MW/browse/REL1_27/img_auth.php;64f7660b6dfd4433f3a5490c99bf1d55dbb3d83e$93) is the culprit. Which code is involved depends on your `$wgFileBackends` etc. configuration, which you should add to your question. You may want to add a `wfDebugLog()` line at that point to get more information.

Anyway, if the only solution found is to add the images to the image table you can add them all with `php maintenance/importImages.php /path/to/images/directory`, see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:ImportImages.php .